# metamacros.h not found, ReactiveCocoa via CocoaPods

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa

When ReactiveCocoa is being installed with CocoaPods, some required files are missing:

metamacros.h, imported in RACTuple.h
EXTScope.h, imported in NSNotificationCenter+RACSupport.h

I tried out different Versions: 2.1.8, 2.4.7, 2.5.0.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- create a new Project with XCode, Single View Application, called "RCFail"
- add a Podfile to the directory with following content:

  pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 2.4.7'

*(or any other version or now explicit version to get 2.5.0 right now)*

- open the RCFail.xcworkspace with XCode 6.3.2
- build the project (or at least, try to build)

**Compiler Output:**

```
RCError/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/RACTuple.h:10:9: 'metamacros.h' file not found
RCError/Pods/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/NSNotificationCenter+RACSupport.m:10:9: fatal error: 'EXTScope.h' file not found
 #import "EXTScope.h"
```

Is there any way to use ReactiveCocoa with CocoaPods right now?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As explained [in this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/issues/12326) one possible reason is that you have an incompatible version of `sed` in your `PATH`. I once had this issue after GNU `sed` was installed by Fink.

However, there are also other reasons why the `prepare_command` in the [linked source](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/ReactiveCocoa/2.3.1/ReactiveCocoa.podspec.json#L21) may fail -- it is, after all, a byzantine command line construction without validation of the employed utilities. Unfortunately, ReactiveCocoa does not officially support CocoaPods, so unless rearranging your `PATH` directories solves your problem you may need to install ReactiveCocoa directly without CocoaPods.

Comment: I kicked off a locally installed sed found in /usr/local/bin. It haven't solved the issue.

It seems that these are bad times now for dependency manager at least regarding ReactiveCocoa. With Pods it failes constantly to the still unfixed issue mentioned in my opener question. So i switched to carthage, but for today, carthage fails also with "Parse error: expected submodule commit SHA in ls-tree output"

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found solution to install ReactiveCocoa without problems. So issue is related to new version of `sed` tool. All you need to do is uninstall `sed` probably installed through `brew`. So jus run command:

`brew uninstall sed`

Then `perpare_command` will use right version of `sed`. To make sure that you have old version of `sed` run command: `$ sed --version`

And the output should be like this:

```
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
   sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```